# How much pressure is needed to force the piston down in an ICE?

Tags: pressure

I know it's different on most cars but what are the force needed on cars you have or worked on.. Is there an average range? I get compression ratios but neee to know the actual force needed to drive that piston down constantly.

Comment: what specific engine are you wondering about?  are you looking for "X Newtons"?  This is HIGHLY dependent on the engine.

Comment: What vehicle are you repairing?

Comment: force needed to drive it down the cylinder manually (when assembling), is the conrod attached to the crankshaft? is the engine in gear? under accelleration, deceleration, constant speed? what type of engine? diesel, petrol, sports car? 4 stroke, 2 stroke? think this question needs a lot of work before it can be answered well.